# Getting GEO location data in Windows using C#

Tags: c#, windows, geolocation, geo

Would it be possible to get GEO location data without connecting to Wi-Fi or any cellular service using C#.

I was trying to use GeoCoordinateWatcher(from System.Device.Location), but it seems to be working only when it's connected to Wi-Fi.

Thanks.

Comment: It has to get the GEO location from somewhere. Do you have another option for windows to get your location? A GPS, for example.

Comment: @FabricioKoch I don't think I have any other option. Is there anything I can install to enable GPS?

Comment: is it windows phone? If so, maybe your cellphone has a GPS. Just turn it on. If it's a PC, then you have to install a GPS hardware to make it works.

Comment: @FabricioKoch, it's not phone. It's windows tab by Getac. Just realized they have in-built app to provide the GPS data. I need to look into how to get this GPS data from another app.

Comment: Some models come with an Integrated GPS. Check if your model has a GPS.

Comment: @FabricioKoch yes, the model has got GPS integrated. https://sharpgps.codeplex.com/ looks like working for me at the moment.

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location)?